# scroll to element in horizontal div

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll

I have a horizontal div:

[image: horizontal div]

i need to scroll to the specific element in this div via JavaScript button (after the click div must be scrolled to that element). How can I do this?

```
<div class="group" id="frames">
<div class="item frames-item">
<img src="1.jpg">
</div>
<div class="item frames-item">    
<img src="2.jpg">
</div>
....
....
</div>
```

Comment: what code have you tried?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

[$.scrollTo](https://github.com/flesler/jquery.scrollTo) is your friend:

```
$(container).scrollTo(target)
```

Comment: @trippincat why? Then just inspect what scrollTo does, and replicate that.

Comment: Super, but that linked page is missing.

Comment: @MatthewSchinckel thank you for pointing out, I updated the answer with current link ^^

Comment: Just clarifying. you will need to install the **jquery.scrollTo** plugin.

Answer (score 49):

Or you could use the following snippet:

```
$('.scrollable').animate({scrollLeft: $('#dstElement').position().left}, 500);
```

Where [`position()`](http://api.jquery.com/position/) returns the `#dstElement`'s relative position to `.scrollable' if scrollable is positioned.

## Code & Demo

```js
    var $scroller = $('.scroller');
    // assign click handler
    $('button').on('click', function () {       
        // get the partial id of the div to scroll to
        var divIdx = $('input').val();          
        
        // retrieve the jquery ref to the div
        var scrollTo = $('#d'+divIdx)           
            // change its bg
            .css('background', '#9f3')          
            // retrieve its position relative to its parent
            .position().left;                   
        console.log(scrollTo);
        // simply update the scroll of the scroller
        // $('.scroller').scrollLeft(scrollTo); 
        // use an animation to scroll to the destination
        $scroller
          .animate({'scrollLeft': scrollTo}, 500);    
    });
```

```css
    .scroller {
        width: 300px;
        height: 100px;
        overflow-x: auto;
        overflow-y: hidden;
    }
    .container {
        position: relative; /*important for the .position() method */
        height: 100px;
        width: 770px;
    }
    .container div {
        height: 90px;
        width: 60px;
        float: left;
        margin: 5px;
        background: #39f;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="scroller">
        <div class="container">
            <div id="d1"></div>
            <div id="d2"></div>
            <div id="d3"></div>
            <div id="d4"></div>
            <div id="d5"></div>
            <div id="d6"></div>
            <div id="d7"></div>
           <!-- ... -->           
        </div>
    </div>
    <button>Scroll to: </button> <input type="text" value="4"/>
```

Comment: If you put 4, it works but if you put 2 right after it, it goes to the first one :/

Comment: Finally I found one that actually works! Thanks @Matyas

Comment: why scroll left?  when moving from 1 to 7, it is actually moving to right.

Comment: it is adjusting the "scrollLeft" property. So if you are setting it from 300 to 500 you are actually scrolling right, when you are changing it from 500 to 300 you are scolling left. Similarly as if you were to modify the x coordinate

Comment: what can I do, if I want the `.container` have a dynamic width?

Answer (score 21):

Without jquery:

```
scrollTo(el) {
    const elRight = el.offsetLeft + el.offsetWidth;
    const elLeft = el.offsetLeft;

    const elParentRight = el.parentNode.offsetLeft + el.parentNode.offsetWidth;
    const elParentLeft = el.parentNode.offsetLeft;

    // check if right side of the element is not in view
    if (elRight > elParentRight + el.parentNode.scrollLeft) {
      el.parentNode.scrollLeft = elRight - elParentRight;
    }

    // check if left side of the element is not in view
    else if (elLeft < elParentLeft + el.parentNode.scrollLeft) {
      el.parentNode.scrollLeft = elLeft - elParentLeft;
    }
  }
```

Comment: Literally couldn't find this anywhere. Thanks a ton!

Comment: Thanks a lot save me a lot of time.

Answer (score 10):

Try below function to make element or li in center on click

```
function centerItVariableWidth(target, outer){
  var out = $(outer);
  var tar = $(target);
  var x = out.width();
  var y = tar.outerWidth(true);
  var z = tar.index();
  var q = 0;
  var m = out.find('li');
  //Just need to add up the width of all the elements before our target. 
  for(var i = 0; i < z; i++){
    q+= $(m[i]).outerWidth(true);
  }
  out.scrollLeft(Math.max(0, q - (x - y)/2));
}
```

Comment: Great simple function for lists.

Answer (score 10):

The code below should do the trick:

```js
  document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
      var frames = document.getElementById('frames');
      frames.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
          if (e.target.classList.contains('item')) {
              e.target.parentNode.scrollLeft = e.target.offsetLeft;

          }
      });
  });
```

```css
        body {
            background: red;
        }
        .group{
            width: 300px;
            display: flex;
            position: relative; /* This is important for the js offsetLeft property */
            overflow-x: scroll;
        }
    
        .item{
            width: 200px;
            background: #eee;
            margin-right: 10px;
        }
```

```html
    <div class="group" id="frames">
        <div class="item frames-item">paul</div>
        <div class="item frames-item">coucou</div>
        <div class="item frames-item">jojoij</div>
        <div class="item frames-item">zoie</div>
        <div class="item frames-item">foez</div>
        <div class="item frames-item">popze</div>
        <div class="item frames-item">kvk</div>
        <div class="item frames-item">poe</div>
        <div class="item frames-item">hfihuazf</div>
        <div class="item frames-item">jeeze</div>
        <div class="item frames-item">pposd</div>
        <div class="item frames-item">nvnn</div>
    </div>
```

Comment: I only needed this part "e.target.parentNode.scrollLeft = e.target.offsetLeft;"

Comment: This is great, exactly what I looked for.

Answer (score 3):

```
$(".ui-jqgrid-bdiv").scrollLeft(400);
```

This will work in jqgrid as well as div

Answer (score 2):

If you have an element, that has inner horizontal scroll, you can do as followed by my example: Two arrows with classes that are used, will scroll the element to sides.

In this case, I have  with class .tabs which I need to move. The 500 is time in miliseconds to animate this scroll, so you can kind of have your own slider..

```
var scroll = 0;
  $('.js-move-list-right').click(function(){
    scroll = scroll + 400;
    $('#timeline .tabs').animate({scrollLeft: scroll}, 500);
  });
  $('.js-move-list-left').click(function(){
      scroll = scroll - 400;
      $('#timeline .tabs').animate({scrollLeft: scroll}, 500);

  });
```

Answer (score -2):

```js
    var $scroller = $('.scroller');
    // assign click handler
    $('button').on('click', function () {       
        // get the partial id of the div to scroll to
        var divIdx = $('input').val();          
        
        // retrieve the jquery ref to the div
        var scrollTo = $('#d'+divIdx)           
            // change its bg
            .css('background', '#9f3')          
            // retrieve its position relative to its parent
            .position().left;                   
        console.log(scrollTo);
        // simply update the scroll of the scroller
        // $('.scroller').scrollLeft(scrollTo); 
        // use an animation to scroll to the destination
        $scroller
          .animate({'scrollLeft': scrollTo}, 500);    
    });
```

```css
    .scroller {
        width: 300px;
        height: 100px;
        overflow-x: auto;
        overflow-y: hidden;
    }
    .container {
        position: relative; /*important for the .position() method */
        height: 100px;
        width: 770px;
    }
    .container div {
        height: 90px;
        width: 60px;
        float: left;
        margin: 5px;
        background: #39f;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="scroller">
        <div class="container">
            <div id="d1"></div>
            <div id="d2"></div>
            <div id="d3"></div>
            <div id="d4"></div>
            <div id="d5"></div>
            <div id="d6"></div>
            <div id="d7"></div>
           <!-- ... -->           
        </div>
    </div>
    <button>Scroll to: </button> <input type="text" value="7"/>
```

Comment: great, it works here!