# Scroll HTML table horizontally using JS

Tags: javascript, scroll, html-table

How would I go about scrolling HTML table horizontally to a specified column using JS, I have `overflow: scroll;` on my table and I want to know if I could do something like:

```
myTable.scrollToColumn(column_ID_or_something_here);
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [scroll to element in horizontal div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17574628/scroll-to-element-in-horizontal-div)

Comment: @VishnuBhadoriya I can't use jQuery, I need to know if there is a simple way using only JS.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `scrollIntoView`

```
document.getElementById("column_ID_or_something_here").scrollIntoView(true);
```

If `scrollIntoView` somehow breaks DOM, use `focus()` method. Key point here if element don't have `tabindex` first you need add it.
In your case table column probably don't have tabindex, code will be:

```
element.setAttribute('tabindex', '999'); 
element.focus();
```

If you need this for Selenium here code (Java):

```
((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("arguments[0].setAttribute('tabindex', '999'); arguments[0].focus();", seleniumElement);
```

Comment: Already tried, it literally scrolls to the column and doesn't affect rows at all, so table looks deformed.

Comment: will try it first thing tomorrow morning

Comment: Table still looks deformed.

Comment: Do you have child element like button, input.. or in columns nearly?

Answer (score 0):

first of all, take any one element from that column using document.getElementsByClassName("class_name")[n].
Applying getBoundingClientRect() method will give you that elements' left and right properties with respect to their position on screen as follows,

```
document.getElementsByClassName("class_name")[n].getBoundingClientRect().left
document.getElementsByClassName("class_name")[n].getBoundingClientRect().right
```

if left is negative then you'll have to scroll on right or else you'll have to scroll on left.

table_Element.scrollBy (x, y) will help you to scroll the table.
Put y as 0 as you dont want to scroll vertically and put x as  -1 * (value of left).

Comment: create a fiddle of your code so i can check with your fiddle.

Comment: vadiya yes i fixed it using dgrids internal method as suggested on my other question