# jQuery - Set position of scroll bar if hasClass

Tags: jquery

I am trying to have the `.list` scroll bar automatically be at the position of the `.button` that has the class `.focus` (I don't want an animated scroll, I just want it to already be at the required position on load).

I am hoping to maintain the position where the `.button` with `.focus` is at the far left of the container `.list`.

[image]

```js
$('.button').each(function() {
  var container = $('.list'),
    scrollTo = $(this);

  if (scrollTo.hasClass('focus')) {
    var leftOffset = scrollTo.offset().left - ($(window).width() / 2 - scrollTo.width() / 2) + container.scrollLeft();

    container.animate({
      scrollLeft: leftOffset
    }, 1000);
  }
});
```

```css
.list {
  display: flex;
  overflow-x: scroll;
  width: 250px;
  border: 2px solid;
}

.button {
  width: 150px;
  height: 40px;
  border: 1px solid
}

.focus {
  background: green
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="list">
  <button class="button">Button 1</button>
  <button class="button">Button 2</button>
  <button class="button">Button 3</button>
  <button class="button">Button 4</button>
  <button class="button">Button 5</button>
  <button class="button">Button 6</button>
  <button class="button">Button 7</button>
  <button class="button focus">Button 8</button>
  <button class="button">Button 9</button>
  <button class="button">Button 10</button>
  <button class="button">Button 11</button>
  <button class="button">Button 12</button>
  <button class="button">Button 13</button>
  <button class="button">Button 14</button>
  <button class="button">Button 15</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [scroll to element in horizontal div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17574628/scroll-to-element-in-horizontal-div)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`.scrollLeft()`](https://api.jquery.com/scrollLeft/) method to position the button in the div:

```js
$('div.list').scrollLeft(
  $('button.focus').offset().left - $('div.list').offset().left + $('div.list').scrollLeft()
);
```

```css
.list {
  display: flex;
  overflow-x: scroll;
  width: 250px;
  border: 2px solid;
}

.button {
  width: 150px;
  height: 40px;
  border: 1px solid
}

.focus {
  background: green
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="list">
  <button class="button">Button 1</button>
  <button class="button">Button 2</button>
  <button class="button">Button 3</button>
  <button class="button">Button 4</button>
  <button class="button">Button 5</button>
  <button class="button">Button 6</button>
  <button class="button">Button 7</button>
  <button class="button focus">Button 8</button>
  <button class="button">Button 9</button>
  <button class="button">Button 10</button>
  <button class="button">Button 11</button>
  <button class="button">Button 12</button>
  <button class="button">Button 13</button>
  <button class="button">Button 14</button>
  <button class="button">Button 15</button>
</div>
```

`$('button.focus').offset().left` is almost sufficient to reposition the button, but you also want to factor in the `div.list` position