# How to align these images horizontally and if I add another image it will be added horizontaly

Tags: html, css, web

I'm trying to create a image slider with name and description but when I add another image it added vertically I tried changing the display but nothing happens can you help me with this im only new to css and html

I want to create this kind of image slider
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9R0tP.png)
but instead this one occurs
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IqamY.png)

What I have now:

```css
.services {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 20px;
}

.services-container {
  padding: 0 10vw;
  display: flex;
  overflow-x: auto;
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
}

.services-container::-webkit-scrollbar {
  display: none;
}

.service-card {
  flex: auto;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 300px;
  height: 450px;
  text-align: center;
  margin-right: 40px;
}

.service-image {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 350px;
  width: 100%;
}

.service-thumb {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}
```

```html
<section class="services">
  <button class="pre-btn"> <img src="image/arrow.png" alt=""></button>
  <button class="next-btn"> <img src="image/arrow.png" alt=""></button>
  <div class="service-container">
    <div class="service-card">
      <div class="service-image">
        <img src="image/antiacne.jpg" class="service-thumb" alt="">
      </div>
      <div class="service-info">
        <h2 class="service-name">Anti Acne</h2>
        <p class="service-desc">Description</p>
      </div>
      <div class="service-container">
        <div class="service-card">
          <div class="service-image">
            <img src="image/antiageing.jpg" class="service-thumb" alt="">
          </div>
          <div class="service-info">
            <h2 class="service-name">Anti Aging</h2>
            <p class="service-desc">Description</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

I've tried different display but nothing happens it just crops the image and it doesn't fit the container

Answer (score 0):

The html should be something like this

```css
.services {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.service-container {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
}

.service-card {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<section class="services">
  <button class="pre-btn"> <img src="image/arrow.png" alt=""></button>
  <div class="service-container">
    <div class="service-card">
      <div class="service-image">
        <img src="image/antiacne.jpg" class="service-thumb" alt="">
      </div>
      <div class="service-info">
        <h2 class="service-name">Anti Acne</h2>
        <p class="service-desc">Description</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="service-card">
      <div class="service-image">
        <img src="image/antiacne.jpg" class="service-thumb" alt="">
      </div>
      <div class="service-info">
        <h2 class="service-name">Anti Acne</h2>
        <p class="service-desc">Description</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <button class="next-btn"> <img src="image/arrow.png" alt=""></button>
</section>
```

After that, you can play with your elements and adjust dimensions, colors etc the way you want.

Comment: thankyou it worked but when I added a different image size the div become messy and when I add a fourth image the 3rd and 4th one overlaps, I'm sorry im newbie in css and html

Comment: Could you show me a screenshot of it and explain to me what exactly is that you want to have as result ?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

This is a small and super quick but detailed answer.  I updated the CSS to show how to lay out the visual parts.

What you describe is commonly called a "carousel" where you have move and focus - in this case on your "cards" or often a set of images or pictures.

Two primary navigation techniques are used.  The left/right button navigation and the "thumbnail" or as I set up here a simple set of "titles" to click on to go directly to that "card".

This is not "production ready" with some ugly borders and other elements just to show what is where and make things somewhat more clear.

You can click either the < or > buttons (I used a bootstrap SVG for these so I could resize it and color it on hover, things like that) OR click the "titles" at the bottom - all styled with a combination of grid and flex - not fancy but more to illustrate.

Borrowed some code from https://stackoverflow.com/a/63773123/125981 for the scroll parts.

As for the index parts there are some useful nuggets of information here: [Is it possible to get element's numerical index in its parent node without looping?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4649699/125981)

```js
(function() {
  function getElementIndex(element) {
    return [...element.parentNode.children].indexOf(element);
  }

  function scrollTo(el) {
    const left = el.offsetLeft + el.offsetWidth;
    const parentLeft = el.parentNode.offsetLeft + el.parentNode.offsetWidth;

    //if element in view
    if (left >= parentLeft + el.parentNode.scrollLeft) {
      el.parentNode.scrollLeft = left - parentLeft;
    } else if (left <= el.parentNode.offsetLeft + el.parentNode.scrollLeft) {
      el.parentNode.scrollLeft = el.offsetLeft - el.parentNode.offsetLeft;
    }
  }

  const carousel = document.querySelector('.carousel');
  const left = document.querySelector('.pre-btn');
  const right = document.querySelector('.next-btn');
  const cards = [...document.querySelectorAll('.service-card')];
  const navNames = document.querySelectorAll('.service-name-nav');
  carousel.dataset.currentIndex = 0;

  right.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    const idx = carousel.dataset.currentIndex * 1;
    let nextIndex = idx < (cards.length - 1) ? idx + 1 : 0;
    carousel.dataset.currentIndex = nextIndex;
    scrollTo(cards[nextIndex]);
  });
  left.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    const idx = carousel.dataset.currentIndex;
    let nextIndex = idx <= 0 ? cards.length - 1 : idx - 1;
    carousel.dataset.currentIndex = nextIndex;
    scrollTo(cards[nextIndex]);
  });
  navNames.forEach(elem => elem.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
    const idx = getElementIndex(this);
    carousel.dataset.currentIndex = idx;
    scrollTo(cards[idx]);
  }));
})();
```

```css
:root {
  --carousel-background: #FF000011;
  --nav-button-size: 5em;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-size: 16px;
}

.services {
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 100vh;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: auto 1fr;
  grid-template-columns: var(--nav-button-size) auto var(--nav-button-size);
  grid-template-areas: "leftnav cards rightnav" "mynav mynav mynav";
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  gap: 1.25em;
  border: solid 1px #00ff00;
  background-color: var(--carousel-background);
}

.services .scroll-button,
.services .scroll-button svg {
  width: var(--nav-button-size);
  height: var(--nav-button-size);
  color: #FFFFFF;
  border: none;
  /* background-color: var(--carousel-background);*/
}

.services .scroll-button:hover,
.services .scroll-button svg:hover {
  transform: scale(1.2);
  color: #FFFF00;
}

.services .scroll-button.prev-btn {
  grid-area: leftnav;
}

.service-container.carousel {
  grid-area: cards;
}

.services .scroll-button.next-btn {
  grid-area: rightnav;
}

.service-container {
  overflow: scroll;
  scroll-snap-type: x mandatory;
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  gap: 1.25em;
  border: solid 1px #ff4444;
  align-items: center;
  padding: .5em;
}

.service-container::-webkit-scrollbar {
  display: none;
}

.service-card {
  border: solid 1px #FF00FF;
  display: grid;
  place-items: center;
}

.service-image {
  display: grid;
  place-items: center;
  border: solid green 1px;
  padding: 0.25em;
  background-color: #0000FF11;
}

.service-thumb {
  /* em of 300 X 350 px */
  /*width: 18.75em;
  height: 21.875em;*/
  width: 15em;
  height: 12em;
  border: double #FF0000 3px;
}

.service-container-nav {
  grid-area: mynav;
  /* overflow-x: scroll;
  overflow-y: hidden;*/
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(5em, 1fr));
  grid-auto-rows: 1fr;
  gap: 1em;
  text-align: center;
  border: solid yellow 2px;
}

.service-name-nav {
  border: solid green 2px;
}
```

```html
<section class="services">
  <div class="pre-btn scroll-button"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="16" height="16" fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-chevron-left" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
  <path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M11.354 1.646a.5.5 0 0 1 0 .708L5.707 8l5.647 5.646a.5.5 0 0 1-.708.708l-6-6a.5.5 0 0 1 0-.708l6-6a.5.5 0 0 1 .708 0z"/>
</svg></div>
  <div class="next-btn scroll-button"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="16" height="16" fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-chevron-right" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
  <path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M4.646 1.646a.5.5 0 0 1 .708 0l6 6a.5.5 0 0 1 0 .708l-6 6a.5.5 0 0 1-.708-.708L10.293 8 4.646 2.354a.5.5 0 0 1 0-.708z"/>
</svg></div>
  <div class="service-container carousel">
    <div class="service-card">
      <div class="service-image">
        <img src="image/antiacne.jpg" class="service-thumb" alt="I am first acne">
      </div>
      <div class="service-info">
        <h2 class="service-name">Anti Acne</h2>
        <p class="service-desc">Description</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="service-card">
      <div class="service-image">
        <img src="image/antiageing.jpg" class="service-thumb" alt="I am aging">
      </div>
      <div class="service-info">
        <h2 class="service-name">Anti Aging</h2>
        <p class="service-desc">Description</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="service-card">
      <div class="service-image">
        <img src="image/antiageing.jpg" class="service-thumb" alt="I am not fun">
      </div>
      <div class="service-info">
        <h2 class="service-name">Anti fun</h2>
        <p class="service-desc">Description</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="service-card">
      <div class="service-image">
        <img src="image/antiageing.jpg" class="service-thumb" alt="I am gun">
      </div>
      <div class="service-info">
        <h2 class="service-name">Fun Guys</h2>
        <p class="service-desc">Description</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="service-card">
      <div class="service-image">
        <img src="image/antiageing.jpg" class="service-thumb" alt="I am grape">
      </div>
      <div class="service-info">
        <h2 class="service-name">Tester Out</h2>
        <p class="service-desc">Description</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <nav class="service-container-nav">
    <div class="service-name-nav">Anti Acne</div>
    <div class="service-name-nav">Anti Aging</div>
    <div class="service-name-nav">Anti fun</div>
    <div class="service-name-nav">Fun Guys</div>
    <div class="service-name-nav">Tester Out</div>
  </nav>
</section>
```